# Sending Messages Between Classes Obj-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, message

I'm a newbie in iPhone Programming. I'm trying to send a message from one view controller to another. The idea is that viewControllerA takes information from the user and sends it to viewControllerB. viewControllerB is then supposed to display the information in a label.

viewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface viewControllerA : UIViewController
{
int num;
}
-(IBAction)do;
@end
```

viewControllerA.m

```
#import "viewControllerA.h"
#import "viewControllerB.h"

@implementation viewControllerA

- (IBAction)do {
//initializing int for example
num = 2;
viewControllerB *viewB = [[viewControllerB alloc] init];
[viewB display:num];
[viewB release];
//viewA is presented as a ModalViewController, so it dismisses itself to return to the 
//original view, i know it is not efficient but it is not the problem with my code 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

viewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface viewControllerB : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
- (void)display:(int)myNum;

@end
```

viewControllerB.m

```
#import "viewControllerB.h"
#import "viewControllerA.h"

@implementation viewControllerB

- (void)display:(int)myNum {
NSLog(@"YES");
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myNum]];
}

@end
```

YES is logged successfully, but the label's text does not change. Can sent messages not 
access instance variables or something?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have your IBOutlets connected correctly, you won't see anything no matter what you do in the code, so make sure those are correct first.

Comment: check the answers and if your problem has solved then accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all int with NSInteger.it will solve your problem.

Edit:

Ok,if you have proper connection.

actually what happens, you call the show function from viewA and try to write the text over the label of viewB from here before loading that page dats why you face problem.so for solving this problem you need to send value to viewB and write the text over label in viewDidLoad method. that will solve your problem.

Comment: @jbrennan, i have done this, this problem solves with above solution.You tried this if not then why -1.

Comment: @Ishu, I agree assuming his classes, IBoutlets, etc are setup correctly. This is not c++, use NSInteger

Comment: Ok you can check by making a sample code with this condition.

Comment: @Ishu Gupta — Why do you format normal text as code? makes no sense and looks ugly.

Comment: @jbrennan, NSInteger is a type definition that describes an integer - but it is NOT equivalent to int on 64-bit platforms.
You can examine the typedef by cmd-clicking on NSInteger in Xcode.
NSInteger is defined as int when building a 32-bit app and as long for 64-bit apps.
Most of the time you can replace int with NSInteger, but there are some things to consider when doing so.

Comment: @Ishu Yes, the NSInteger typedef will help future-proof your code and make it do the right thing on other platforms. So I do agree using NSInteger instead of just plain int.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with sending messages the way you are trying. The error is in using 'int' as a type. Use NSInteger in Objective-C to alleviate numerous headaches.

Comment: For iOS targets, `NSInteger` is a typedef of `int`. So when the code is preprocessed, NSInteger just becomes int. So it doesn't solve anything for iOS targets, currently. Though it is a good idea, in case Apple changes the type of NSInteger, your code will automatically gain the benefits. But in this case, it does nothing.

Comment: Ok, point taken. It was the only point of weakness I see in the code presented, but I'm taking for granted that the o.p. has his outlets secured.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your `label` is not pointing to anything (so when you tell it to `setText:`, that message is just being sent to `nil` and thus nothing happens).

Check Interface Builder to make sure you've set the outlet to actually point to the label in your view.

Comment: @JakeVA ,No but i have face this problem before this time.

Comment: first comment for my case which i thought for the poster coz problem is in actual of int not the connection. Ok i change that according to real thinking.

Comment: i have done this all connection set in my view then what will be your advice now for my case(not assuming orignal post).

Comment: you are right actually problem is any thing else.But again connection was not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is there more to your code than what you show here? I don't see how viewB is being shown -- there isn't a [self.view addSubview:viewB.view] or anything to indicate that it would be shown in a view. Perhaps that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you're doing here, and how these view controllers relate to what's onscreen?  My understanding is that viewControllerA is presented as some kind of modal dialog that gathers information?  It's presented by viewControllerB, and when A closes B sets its label onscreen to reflect the value returned from A?

If this is the case, you need to have a reference to B in A, for a couple reasons.
-First, you're initting an instance of B in A's `do` function and telling it to display your number, but I don't see you putting B onscreen anywhere.
-Second, calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on A won't dismiss A, it will dismiss the modal view controller that A presented. So to dismiss A, you need to say `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` on B.  That's best accomplished by having A notify B that it's ready to be closed.